# Spacing around figures and tables

Tags: spacing, floats

At the moment I have the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}  
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
```

This puts figure captions below the figure, and table captions above the tables (this is what I want).

For some reason, this  leaves a relatively large empty area **below** tables. Figures do not have this problem, as the caption is there to fill part of the space. At the same time, the spacing **above** tables and figures is very small (would like it bigger). Is there an easy way to control the spacing in this environment?

Comment: Can you include a minimum working example (MWE) and a screenshot of the observed behavior you're experiencing?  It's hard to recreate/visualize your issue without this.

Comment: You could use \vspace, but it would be just as easy to not use the float package in the first place.